# Angular unit test with karma jasmine and browserify

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, gulp, karma-jasmine, browserify

I am using [this](https://github.com/mjhea0/angular-gulp-browserify-seed) repo code to apply browserify in app. I want to write unit test for my app for this I include karma and karma browserify. My folder structure is :

[image]

**karma.config.js**

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',
    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine' , 'browserify'],
    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'node_modules/angular/angular.js',
      'node_modules/angular-router/angular-router.js',
      'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'app/js/main.js',
      'app/js/specs/main.spec.js'
    ],
    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [],
   // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
      'app/js/specs/main.spec.js': [ 'browserify' ]
    },
    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],
    // web server port
    port: 9876,
    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,
    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,
    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,
    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity,
    browserify: {
      watch: true,
      debug: true,
      plugin: ['karma-browserify']
    }
  })
}
```

**package.json**

```
    {
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Ghazanfar Khan",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.6.7",
    "angular-animate": "^1.6.7",
    "angular-mocks": "^1.6.7",
    "angular-route": "^1.6.7",
    "bower": "^1.8.2",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-browserify": "^0.5.1",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.3.2",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-connect": "^5.0.0",
    "gulp-jshint": "^2.0.4",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^1.2.4",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.8.0",
    "jshint": "^2.9.5",
    "karma": "^1.7.1",
    "karma-browserify": "^5.1.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.1",
    "run-sequence": "^2.2.0",
    "watchify": "^3.9.0"
  }
}
```

When I am executing karma start it gives me error

> Error: plugin karma-browserify exported a object, expected a function
>       at Browserify.plugin (C:\Users\User\Desktop\sample app\UnitTestApp\node_modules\browserify\index.js:457:28)

I am confused to write unit test code by using angular.mocks.module fashion or using require for module mock in writing test . Need a simple example to write a unit test according to this structure .